# ASP.NET C#: How do i properly use async-await to show a label before heavy logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am trying to simply show a label that shows a user that the application is processing some data. The break down of what I am trying to do:

1. User clicks button
2. Label displays saying "Loading data..."
3. Execute Method
4. Await the Method
5. Label from step 2 should now display "Done Upload!"

I was able to accomplish all except step 2. My code does not display the "Loading data..." prior to executing the method - it simply runs the methods and displays "Done Upload!" after the execution.

I was hoping to figure out why my code is not executing step 2 and how I can change my code to show the initial "Loading data..." in my label.

Please and thank you!

Here is my button click:

```
protected async void Sync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblProgress.Text = "Loading data...";

            Task<String> task = new Task<string>(SyncPath);
            task.Start();

            String result = await task;
            lblProgress.Text = result;

        }
```

Here is my method:

```
 private String SyncPath()
        {

           // do heavy stuff

            return "Done Upload!";

        }
```

I expect the user to see the initial "Loading data..." text in the label and then code execution followed by "Done Upload" in the aforementioned label. However, the user does not see the initial "Loading data..." but only see the "Done Upload" after the code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the page will not be updated until it has been reloaded.  `Sync_Click` is working as you intend but it runs on the server and the page will not be updated because it runs on the client.

You need to have an ajax [update panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.8) and the label should go inside it.  Then you can update the label text without reloading the entire page.

Comment: Hi fireydude, i tried putting the label in an update panel but i didn't seem to work. Am i doing something else wrong? Here is the page content:

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Label ID="lblProgress" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>


            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>